# Match one item in List of tuples

Tags: list, ocaml

I have a List of tuples of the form `(string, int)`.  I'm trying to search through the list and return the tuple whose string component matches the parameter, as in: `let find_tuple string_name tuples_list =`

How can I do this?  I can't quite wrap my head around it.  Is there a way to use matching syntax like `(string, _) ->...`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve this as following

```
let rec find_tuple string_name tuples_list =
       match tuples_list with
            [] -> raise Not_found
            |(s, i)::tl -> if s = string_name then (s, i) 
                                  else find_tuple string_name tl
```

or simply

```
List.find (fun s -> fst s = string_name) tuples_list
```

Comment: You can use the `as` keyword to simplify things a little bit: `| ((s, i) as h)::tl -> if ... then h else ...`  Also, didn't know about the `fst` function, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: The second option can also be written as `List.find (fun (string, _) -> string = string_name) tuples_list`, which has the `(string, _)` the OP wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you do use matching syntax like that, but will need match guards (or you can use if then else).  The `List` module has a function called `find` that will return the first element that matches a predicate.  It also has the function `filter` (and `find_all` - same function) that returns a list of all the elements that match the predicate.  For example:

```
let predicate string_name tuple = match tuple with (s, _) when s = string_name -> true
  | _ false

try
  let x = List.find (predicate "query") tuples_list in
    ...
  with Not_found -> ...
```

EDIT: a better predicate:

```
let predicate string_name (s, _) = s = string_name
```

However the better solution is to use `List.assoc` which works on lists of tuples, and considers the tuples to be key-value pairs:

```
try
  let x = List.assoc "query" tuples_list in ...
with Not_found -> ...
```

Although the return value of `List.assoc` is the second element of the tuple (an `int` in your case).  If you want the value of the tuple, either recreate it, or use the first approach.