# OCaml List.mem to search element in list of pair

Tags: ocaml

I have this question:

```
let list  = [(1,2);(2,3);(1,4);(5,0)];;
List.mem (1,2) list;;
- : bool = true
```

But I need to modify this function to have "True/False" when the one element pair of list match with the "find parameter" for example

```
List.mem (1,_) list;;
- : bool = true
```

Or

```
List.mem (10,_) list;;
- : bool = false
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Match one item in List of tuples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4473163/match-one-item-in-list-of-tuples)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `List.exists`, which takes a predicate function and returns `true` or `false` whether an element of the list matches or not:

```
# let list  = [(1,2);(2,3);(1,4);(5,0)];;
val list : (int * int) list = [(1, 2); (2, 3); (1, 4); (5, 0)]
(* you'll probably want to find a better name *)
# let exists_left list value = List.exists (fun (x, _) -> x = value) list;;
val exists_left : ('a * 'b) list -> 'a -> bool = <fun>
# exists_left list 1;;
- : bool = true
# exists_left list 100;;
- : bool = false
```

Answer (score 5):

`List.mem_assoc` is the function you want.